# Uso de la funcion Switch dentro del ciclo For c++

Tags: c++

Debo escribir un programa que escriba los números comprendidos entre 1 y 200. El programa escribirá en la pantalla los números en grupos de 20, solicitando al usuario si quiere o no continuar visualizando el siguiente grupo de números.

Tengo dos problemas, el primero es que cuando ejecuto el programa el contador (i) este no me sale en la pantalla.

El segundo problema es que no se como hacer para cuando el valor de (i) sea mayor a 20, o sea 21 (cuando ya se haya cumplido el mostrar el grupo de 20 numeros) el usuario tenga que ingresar nuevamente el numero 1 para mostrarle los 20 numeros siguientes (por ejemplo, en este caso hasta el 40)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){

    int op=0;

    for (int i=1; i<201; i++){
        cout<<"Desea ver el siguiente conjunto de 20 numeros? "<<endl;
        cout<<"1 = Continuar "<<endl;
        cout<<"2 = Declinar "<<endl;
        cin>>op;
        switch(op){
            case 1:  cout<<i<<endl;
                     if(i>20){
                        cin>>op; } break;
            case 2: return 0;break;

            default: cout<<"Opcion invalida "<<endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Esto es lo que sucede

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El programa hace lo que le indicaste. Que sería imprimir el mensaje en cada iteración el diálogo.

Podrías plantearlo de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>

// Imprime los números en el rango [inicio, fin]
void subconjunto(int inicio, int fin){
    if (inicio > fin)
        return;

    for (int i = inicio; inicio <= fin; i++){
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}

int main(){
    int i = 1, op = 0;
    
    do {
        subconjunto(i, i + 20);
        
        std::cout << "Desea ver el siguiente conjunto de 20 numeros? " << '\n';
        std::cout << "1 = Continuar "<< '\n';
        std::cout << "2 = Declinar " << '\n';
        std::cin >> op;

        i += 20;
    } while (i < 200 && op == 1);
}
```

De esta forma, imprimes de a 20 elementos con ayuda de una función y preguntas si deseas continuar. Haciendo el código más fácil de entender.

Otra manera es imprimir el mensaje cada 20 iteraciones. Podrías lograrlo con ayuda de una variable adicional o verificar si   `i % 20 == 0 && i > 0`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!