# Condicial anidadas a un ciclo for dentro de varios switch c++

Tags: c++

Debo realizar un programa que me imprima los numeros comprendidos entre 1 y 200, ir mostrando los primeros numeros en grupos de 20 (1 hasta el 20) y cuando toque mostrar los nuevos nuevamente el grupo de 20 (que en este caso sería del 20 hasta el 40) le pregunte al usuario si desea continuar para seguir mostrando los que siguen, así hasta llegar al 200.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){

    int op;

    for(int i=1; i<201; i++){
        cout<<i<<endl;
        if(i>19){
            cout<<"Desea continuar? "<<endl;
            cout<<" 1 = Si "<<endl;
            cout<<" 2 = No "<<endl;
            cin>>op;
            switch(op){
                case 1: cout<<i<<endl;
                        if(i==40){
                            cout<<"Desea continuar: "<<endl;
                            cout<<" 1 = Si "<<endl;
                            cout<<" 2 = No "<<endl;
                            cin>>op;
                            switch(op){
                                case 1: cout<<i<<endl;
                                        if(i>59){
                                            cout<<"Desea continuar: "<<endl;
                                            cout<<" 1 = Si "<<endl;
                                            cout<<" 2 = No "<<endl;
                                            cin>>op; 
                                            switch(op){
                                                case 1: cout<<i<<endl;
                                                        if(i>79){
                                                            cout<<"Desea continuar: "<<endl;
                                                            cout<<"1 = Si "<<endl;
                                                            cout<<"2 = No "<<endl;
                                                            cin>>op;
                                                            switch(op){
                                                                case 1: cout<<i<<endl;
                                                                if(i>99){
                                                                cout<<"Desea continuar: "<<endl;
                                                                cout<<"1 = Si "<<endl;
                                                                cout<<"2 = No "<<endl;
                                                                cin>>op;
                                                                switch(op){
                                                                    case 1: cout<<i<<endl;
                                                                    if(i>119){
                                                                        cout<<"Desea continuar: "<<endl;
                                                                        cout<<"1 = Si "<<endl;
                                                                        cout<<"2 = No "<<endl;
                                                                        cin>>op;
                                                                        switch(op){
                                                                            case 1: cout<<i<<endl;
                                                                            if(i>139){
                                                                                cout<<"Desea continuar: "<<endl;
                                                                                cout<<"1 = Si "<<endl;
                                                                                cout<<"2 = No "<<endl;
                                                                                cin>>op;
                                                                                switch(op){
                                                                                    case 1: cout<<i<<endl;
                                                                                    if(i>159){
                                                                                        cout<<"Desea continuar: "<<endl;
                                                                                        cout<<"1 = Si "<<endl;
                                                                                        cout<<"2 = No "<<endl;
                                                                                        cin>>op;
                                                                                        switch(op){
                                                                                            case 1: cout<<i<<endl;
                                                                                            if(i>179){
                                                                                                cout<<"Desea continuar: "<<endl;
                                                                                                cout<<"1 = Si "<<endl;
                                                                                                cout<<"2 = No "<<endl;
                                                                                                cin>>op;
                                                                                                switch(op){
                                                                                                    case 1: cout<<i<<endl;
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            }
                                                                                            case 2: return 0;
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    case 2: return 0;
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                            case 2: return 0;
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                    case 2: return 0;
                                                                } 
                                                                }
                                                                case 2: return 0;
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                case 2: return 0;}
                                        }
                                case 2: return 0;break;}
                        }break;
                case 2: return 0;break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

El problema que tengo es que a la hora de ejecutar el codigo, este me imprime los 20 primeros numeros pero cuando salta la primera pregunta (si deseo continuar o no) y le doy que si, solamente me imprime un numero adicional (21) en lugar de los otros 20 numeros que le siguen (hasta el 40), soy consciente de que mi codigo es poco ortodoxo y bastante largo, pero me gustaría en lo posible dejarlo como esta pero entendiendo el funcionamiento de los switch aninados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu codigo puede quedar mucho mas corto y es facil de hacerlo, no entiendo pq quieres dejarlo asi, cuando veas q tan corto puede quedar te vas a asombrar

Comment: Por más principiante que seas, es un código muy difícil de mantener. Hasta a ti mismo te debe haber costado trabajo entenderlo.

Comment: Por cierto, ya hiciste [una pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/540070/169744). El código no difiere mucho. Solo has complicado el problema. Si te quedan dudas sobre lo mismo, edita la pregunta o hazlo saber en los comentarios. No nos importa tener que editar las respuestas algunas veces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No entiendo la complicación de tu código, que puede escribirse así:

```
int op;

for (int numero = 1; numero != 200; ++numero)
{
    if (!(numero % 20))
    {
        std::cout <<
            "Desea continuar?\n"
            "1 = Si\n"
            "2 = No\n";

        std::cin >> op;

        if (op == 2)
            return 0;
    }

    std::cout << numero << '\n';
}
```

Respecto a tu problema: Cada vez que repites el bucle, se cumple la primera condición:

```
if(i>19){
```

Ya que cualquier número a partir del 19 será mayor que 19; por lo tanto a cada número te hace la misma pregunta.

Comment: Te falla el 200, que no lo imprimes, por sacarle algun fallo al código

Comment: Supongo que con `numero <= 200` se arregla.

Answer (score 1):

Tu codigo puede reescribirse de esta forma:

```
#include <iostream>

#define RANGE_JUMP  20 //definimos de cuanto en cuanto queremos que se impriman los numeros.
#define RANGE_LIMIT RANGE_JUMP * 10 //definimos hasta que numero queremos llegar.

typedef unsigned short int iter_size; //creamos un tipo para iterar sobre nuestro bucle for. 

//system("cls") limpia la consola. Usar "cls" si te encuentras en Windows. Si estas en linux el 
//comando correcto seria: system("clear") 

int main()
{
    using std::cout; using std::cin;

    iter_size acc = 20; //variable que nos permitira manejar paulatinamente los lotes de numeros. 

    for (iter_size i = 0; i < RANGE_LIMIT; i = i + 1) {
        if (i <= acc) {
            cout << i << '\n';
        }
        else {
        menu:
            unsigned short int user_option;
            cout << "Menu de opciones:\n";
            cout << "1. Imprimir el siguiente lote de numeros.\n";
            cout << "2. Terminar.\n";
            cout << "Ingrese su opcion aqui: ";
            cin >> user_option;

            if (user_option == 1) {               
                acc = acc + RANGE_JUMP; //incrementamos el lote segun lo indicado.
                i = i - 1; //decrementamos una vez a i para que la secuencia numerica no se vea afectada. 
                system("cls");
            }
            else if (user_option == 2) {
                std::cout << "\nPrograma terminado...\n";
                system("pause");
                break;
            }
            else {
                system("cls");
                cout << "\nOpcion incorrecta, vuelva a intentarlo...\n";
                goto menu; //se repetira la impresion del menu en caso que se ingrese una opcion invalida. 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El uso `goto` se considera mala práctica. Especialmente por practicantes de la programación estructurada. Algunos también repudian a `break` y `continue` ya que como `goto`, hacen más difícil seguir el código y por ende, lo hacen menos legible. En C++ también se recomienda el uso de variables `constexpr` sobre `#define`.

Comment: Lo del `goto` no tiene nada que ver con la depurabilidad. Solo que [hace al código más difícil de mantener](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3517726/13419694). Sobre `break` y `continue`, me gusta usarlos. Pero un profesor que tuve es bastante conservador respecto a la programación estructurada y los rechaza. De hecho, también [hay discusión al respecto](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/58237).

Comment: Muchisimas gracias a todos por su respuesta, tu codigo me sirvio mucho para entender muchas cositas de las que tenia duda!! seguire metiendome en este mundillo para ir entendiendo más y más

Comment: Perfecto, ya mismo lo hago :)